# What are the rules for a JSF id?

Tags: jsf

It seems like I should be able to find this with a half hour of searching the webs, but since I cannot:

**What are the rules for valid JSF ids?**

I read a garbled e-mail message that suggested there were limitations on `-` and `_`, but I'm getting IllegalArgumentExceptions and I think it's due to the ids.

**EDIT**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 6a945017207d46fd82b3d3bb7d2795f1
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:549)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:351)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:151)
```

Comment: Why don't you just post the exception stacktrace and the code snippet that caused it?

Comment: I don't think I can par down the example to anything reasonably simple that would demonstrate the issue, but I'll attach the stack trace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It has to be a valid [CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) (the `ident` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)) and there should be no duplicates.

> In CSS, identifiers  (including element names, classes, and IDs in [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)) can contain only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and ISO 10646 characters `U+00A1` and higher, plus the hyphen (`-`) and the underscore (`_`); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier `"B&W?"` may be written as `"B\&W\?"` or `"B\26 W\3F"`.

#### See also:

- [Allowed characters for CSS identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers/2812097#2812097)

---

**Update**: for the case you're interested, here's the source code of the validator as provided by `UIComponentBase#validateId()`:

```
private static void validateId(String id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return;
    }
    int n = id.length();
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty id attribute is not allowed");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = id.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c) && (c != '_')) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(id);
            }
        } else {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c) &&
                    !Character.isDigit(c) &&
                    (c != '-') && (c != '_')) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's however a little more strict than the CSS rules. They cannot start with a hyphen as well.

Comment: BINGO! can't start with a digit! I appreciate the whole page because I could spend all day replaceing characters and appending text and not get all the rules right 100% of the time. Thanks

Comment: @BalusC is there any reason, to be more restrictive than [HTML rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1099452)? Only to allow easier CSS selection?

Comment: @lucasvc: HTML rules allow `:`, which conflicts naming container separator character.

Comment: @BalusC But container separtor, can be configured, right? And in my case, the problem is with period / dot / `.`.

Comment: @lucasvc: it was only since JSF 2.0 configurable.

Comment: Still, `update=":form-list-users:table-list-users"` cannot be solved. And I was about to rename my ids again. Almost all of them have `-` and still some have `_` in their names. Else only `[a-z]` is included, no numbers at all. `table-list-users` is a `p:dataTable`.

Comment: @Roland You have actually a different question than the one asked here. Move on to https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634156

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. I found already the fix for it: I used `p:page` which adds another id fragment to the final id `update` requires. So I set `p:page id="master"` and I can use `update=":master:what-ever-here"` successfully. Thank you replying anyway.