# Integer not allowed as values for attributes id

Tags: jsp, primefaces, xhtml

I have a java class named Test which has an attribute `Integer id` (auto-increment). It's initialized with value 1.

In my xhtml file I want to give every column I create, the id from the java bean class.

And in another class (java bean class) named AnotherClass with annotation :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myClass")
@ApplicationScoped
```

And I have a list of Test in this class.

This is what I tried to do, but it doesn't recognize integers as value for id attributes. In the documentation it says that only strings are allowed. How can I proceed ?

```
<c:forEach items="#{myclass.list}" var="test">
    <p:column id="#{test.id}" headerText="#{test.header}">
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: In html an ID cannot start with a number. JSF honors this...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972433/what-are-the-rules-for-a-jsf-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for a JSF id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972433/what-are-the-rules-for-a-jsf-id)

Comment: Next time also try with a simple plain `h:inputText` or whatever. If that fails, you **know** it is not column related.... Simplify... [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje I see, I will edit the title then. So there aren't any way to do what I want ?

Comment: For now I've just added a caracter before the integer : id="t#{test.id}", but it's kind of ugly.

Comment: It is not ugly... it is working within html4 (and css) limitations... You could also make it `"col#{test.id}"` html5 allows it but css still does not

Comment: html5 allows to begin the id with an integer ?

Comment: It seems so but css still does not really so it is uncommon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method called `String getIdAsString()` then use it instead of id getter:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myclass.list}" var="test">
    <p:column id="#{test.idAsString}" headerText="#{test.header}">
</c:forEach>
```

The `getIdAsString()` method should give some prefix from letters `[a-z|A-Z]` becuse an html id is not allowed to start with digit. So the implementation could be:

```
public String getIdAsString() {
  return "id"+id.toString();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it says : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2 (2 is the value of id)

Comment: @Gatsby checkout my answer again

Comment: @Kukeltje from where do you infer that the implementation of `getIdAsString` method is returning an invalid html id? It is up to the @Gatsby how He will implement it. I didn't say that He should (or not) return just digits. So your downvote is somehow inadequate.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki As mentionned, you're solution isn't working but thanks  anyway.

Comment: @Gatsby please do check again with the suggested implementation of `getIdAsString()`

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki yes this is what I finally decided to do. But directly in the id attribute.

Comment: You did miss a lot of stating things explicitly AND trying... and relying on my help... I still think this is not the right solution and the one @Gatsby used (and what I mentioned in my previous comment) is the better way to go...

Comment: @Kukeltje this is SO, we all rely here on helping each other.